# Visual studio 2013 database publish do nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to publish a DB project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional and the "Publish" button do nothing.
In project properties I checked "Create script (.sql file)". I right click the project name in solution explorer > Publish... > Load Profile (a profile that works for my colleagues) > Publish

Nothing Happens, not an error, warning or anything (same with "Generate Scripts" button).
Visual studio error logs say nothing and I tried to restart the PC, Visual studio and SQL server.

Thank you!

Comment: Same happening here. I opened the solution from 1 branch of TFS, clicked Publish and it worked fine. Then I opened a different branch, clicked publish and nothing. Now when I try to close VS, I get an error saying "The solution cannot be closed while publishing". Nothing in the UI suggests it is publishing and there is no VSDBCMD types process running

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to publish a database project while having an Azure blob explorer open. Closing the blob explorer made the publish work again.

Comment: I'm still having these problems in 2020 with VS2019 and SQL 2019.  You'd think they would have fixed this by now.

Comment: After reading about Azure queue open making it hang, I checked for Azure Queue.  I didn't see it but closed all tabs (for files) just in case and that worked.  BTW I'm on VS2019.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Azure Cloud Explorer window open in Visual Studio (could be table, blob or queue), that leads to the Publish of an SSDT project hanging.

Close the window and start a new Publish operation. It may take a little longer than usual but eventually that will progress and you'll be able to close Visual Studio as normal.

Thanks to Noel Abrahams for his comment that led to this answer.

*EDIT: putting it here as an answer so that it can be more easily found but credit goes to Noel.*

Comment: @krlzlx Modified to be more specific while retaining credit for Noel.

Comment: Good. Now it's a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix on the [MS Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812846/sql-publish-hangs-in-visual-studio-2013-and-cannot-close-application).

In my publish profile I had set the connection string as so:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=.\sql2008r2;Integrated Security=SSPI;</TargetConnectionString>
```

According to the comments on Connect, it doesn't like `Integrated Security=SSPI`. Instead you should use `Integrated Security=True;`:

```
<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=.\sql2008r2;Integrated Security=True;</TargetConnectionString>
```

Then it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the solution from VCS to a new directory and only this helped.

Other symptoms that I had with this issue:

- While editing a table `.sql` script, Design pane didn't work.
- `Integrated Security=True;` was set in my publishing profile. So Rhumborl's answer is not about my case.
- If the solution folder is copied to another machine the issue is reproduced there too.

I tried to Clean Solution before re-cloning, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me publishing the database project to a new sql server database with a different name allowed the publish to proceed.  Once I'd done that I was then able to publish to the original database again.

Answer (score 0):

I found that having an Azure Queue or Blob Storage opened in Visual Studio Professional 2015 meant that clicking Publish did nothing and I couldn't close the application. After closing those windows which I had launched from the Cloud Explorer, I had to click Publish once again to kick it off. A strange bug.